# MS Access update query asks for parameter value - query depending on select query

Tags: ms-access, sql-update

The `UPDATE` query below interprets `qry_Breakd_DYFYHAS_CountRecsDateRange.CountRecords_InDateRange` to be a parameter and asks for a parameter value.

The `qry_Breakd_DYFYHAS_CountRecsDateRange` query works, and gives the number: 8.

Contents of `Update` query:

```
    UPDATE tbl_total_listenings_calcs 
    SET tbl_total_listenings_calcs.Total_listenings_tbl_Data_DateRange = qry_Breakd_DYFYHAS_CountRecsDateRange.CountRecords_InDateRange;
```

Contents of "qry_Breakd_DYFYHAS_CountRecsDateRange" query:

```
    SELECT count(*) AS CountRecords_InDateRange
    FROM tbl_Data, tbl_DateFromTo
    WHERE (((tbl_Data.Date_Listening) Between tbl_DateFromTo.Date_From And tbl_DateFromTo.Date_To));
```

Seeking advice and suggestions on what to change in the two queries as applicable to get the `update` query working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `UPDATE` references only `tbl_total_listenings_calcs`, and it is not joined to any other table or query.  So when Access sees `qry_Breakd_DYFYHAS_CountRecsDateRange.CountRecords_InDateRange`, all it knows is that is not one of the query's data sources, so assumes it must be a parameter.

Use `DLookup()` to fetch the `CountRecords_InDateRange` value from the `qry_Breakd_DYFYHAS_CountRecsDateRange` query.

```sql
UPDATE tbl_total_listenings_calcs 
SET Total_listenings_tbl_Data_DateRange = 
    DLookup
        (
            "CountRecords_InDateRange",
            "qry_Breakd_DYFYHAS_CountRecsDateRange"
        );
```

You could check whether it works with a subquery instead of `DLookup()` ...

```sql
UPDATE tbl_total_listenings_calcs 
SET Total_listenings_tbl_Data_DateRange = 
    (
        SELECT CountRecords_InDateRange
        FROM qry_Breakd_DYFYHAS_CountRecsDateRange
    );
```

However, sometimes Access treats an `UPDATE` with a subquery as *"not updateable"*.  I'm not certain what would happen in this case.  But `DLookup()` will surely work.

Comment: Ok I'll try those and let you have feedback soon.

Comment: You are missing a comma, between the fieldname and the query name in the Dlookup. Then the Dlookup works. Thanks